# Scanner not working(C code)

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float calculateBalance(float payment, float balance, float rate);

int main(void){
    float loanAmount, interestRate, monthlyPayment;

    printf("Enter amount of loan:");
    scanf("%.2f", &loanAmount);

    printf("\nEnter interest rate:");
    scanf("%.1f", &interestRate);

    printf("\nEnter monthly payment:");
    scanf("%.2f", &monthlyPayment);

    loanAmount = calculateBalance(monthlyPayment, loanAmount, interestRate);
    printf("Balance remaining after first payment: %.2f\n", loanAmount);

    loanAmount = calculateBalance(monthlyPayment, loanAmount, interestRate);
    printf("Balance remaining after second payment: %.2f\n", loanAmount);

    loanAmount = calculateBalance(monthlyPayment, loanAmount, interestRate);
    printf("Balance remaining after third payment: %.2f\n", loanAmount);
}

float calculateBalance(float payment, float balance, float rate){
    return (balance-payment + balance*rate);
}
```

I am trying to calculate the balance after three payments are made; However, when I try and run the code in terminal, it's not letting me input anything, and instead is just reading in random numbers and then calculating the balance after three payments(I want to be able to input things, but it isn't allowing me to). How do I fix this?

Comment: `scanf` doesn't recognize `%.2f`. Simply use `%f`.

Comment: @T.C. Wrong one apparently :/

Comment: @self. What does `.` do according to the documentation?

Comment: Also, this is obviously a school assignment, but it's worth noting  that you shouldn't be using `float` (or `double` or even `long double`) for any sort of actual financial calculations.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in the fmt string itself. As @T.C. said in a comment

try using

```
scanf("%f", &var);
```

instead. If there are only 2 dec values, then it will only read that.

Answer (score -1):

You can try a adding a `getc(stdin);` after each scanf.